# reachability function in swift 4 xcode 9

Tags: xcode, swift4, wkwebview, reachability

I want to make reachability function in xcode 9 but I got this error when do reachability class, how to fix this error? "Value of type 'SCNetworkReachability?' has no member 'takeRetainedValue'". Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)


        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are many errors when compiling the code in Swift 4.

A Swift 4 compatible version is (please name classes with a starting uppercase letter)

```
public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr()
        zeroAddress.sa_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr>.size)
        zeroAddress.sa_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }) else { return false }

        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        guard SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) else { return false }

        return flags.contains(.reachable) && !flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
    }

}
```